# Linking to statically compiled z3 needs additional libraries on Linux

Tags: z3, static-linking

I used CMake to compile a static version of (a fairly recent of) z3 using:

```
cmake -DBUILD_LIBZ3_SHARED=false -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/z3-devel -G "Unix Makefiles" ../
```

Now when I statically link the library against a C++ program, say this small variation of a z3 example:

```
#include"z3++.h"
using namespace z3;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  config conf;
  context c(conf);
  expr x = c.int_const("x");
  expr y = c.int_const("y");
  expr z = c.int_const("z");
  goal g(c);
  g.add( ((2*x)+y)+z == 4);
  g.add( (x+(2*y))+z == 4);
  g.add( x+y == 4);
  std::cout << g << "\n";
  tactic t(c, "fm");
  apply_result r = t(g);
  std::cout << r << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

via

```
g++ -c -I /opt/z3-devel/include -static -o main.o main.cc
g++ -static -L /opt/z3-devel/lib64 -o main main.o -lz3
```

I receive a long list of undefined reference linking errors. What solves the issue is to add `-lgomp -pthread -lrt -ldl` as additional libraries. The linker outputs the following warning:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/libgomp.a(target.o): in function `gomp_target_init':
(.text+0x32c): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

Nevertheless, the program runs fine on my own machine and on Starexec.

Is this combination of static and dynamic linking the best I can do? Shouldn't those libraries be already statically linked into libz3.a? I have static versions of gomp, pthread and rt available on the system.

Comment: One immediate thought: I remember that at least on Windows, OpenMP is not available in static form, so the build scripts may be set up to use the dynamic libraries regardless of the target. Going by the warning message from the linker, it looks to be similar on your platform though.

Comment: That's well possible - if I understand the cmake flag correctly, this just expresses a preference of static libraries over dynamic ones.It might make sense to raise an issue at the github repository then -- I just want to make sure that this is not a specific problem that only occurs for me.